# Add "constant" value in xib in auto layout ios

Tags: ios, autolayout, swift4

I have successfully set AutoLayout for iPhone8+,iPhone X,iphone 7 but there is problem for iPhone SE i.e Reduced the space between two labels, so I need to change "constant value" in constraints but I don't want to add outlet add to constant value is there any possibility for add constant value for iPhone SE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

storyboard solution:

> screen width (or super view's width)
>   ⬇︎
>   base view's leading
>   ⬇︎
>   target view's spacing between base view.

use left button as the **base reference**, set right or target button's **trailing** constraint with left button's **leading**(or something else horizontal), and set target button's 
constraint with **multiplier**.

[image: adding spacing between buttons using multiplier]

change multiplier value based on storyboard's virtual view, that's easy.

set left button's **leading** based on its' super view's **trailing**, also with **multiplier**, so left button's leading based on super view's width, and the right
button based on super view's width too, the spacing between them will grow or shrink with the actual screen size.

case all these iPhone devices are (wC, hR), so, so can not set size classes in storyboard, but, you can still check screen size and make your own logic to layout based on screen sizes in code.

[image]

hope this post may help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a class and following code in it.

```
import UIKit

class DynamicVerticalConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint {


override init() {
    super.init()
    updateConstant()
}



override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    updateConstant()
}
//It will send contraint constant according to devices. For this you have to set your contraint according to iPhone6
func updateConstant(){

    self.constant = self.constant * (UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 667)

}
}

class DynamicHorizontalConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint {


override init() {
    super.init()
    updateConstant()
}



override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    updateConstant()
}
//It will send contraint constant according to devices. For this you have to set your contraint according to iPhone6
func updateConstant(){
    self.constant = self.constant * (UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 375)
}
```

}

Now set your constraint's constant value according to iphone 6.
After that you have to assign class to specific contrant.

Comment: Thank you but Without programmatically in xib is it possible?

Comment: i dont think so you can do it specifically for iPh0ne SE with xib.

Comment: From the above solution , you dont need to create outlet for your constraints ,just assign the class  lol